# Use Hash Tag and () in launching URL with Bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have this command in a unix Bash Shell Script:

```
midori http://www.test.com/test.php?id=$i&test=yes#test(test) &
```

But I get:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How do I use this?

Comment: `midori "http://www.test.com/test.php?id=$i&test=yes#test(test)" &`?

Comment: Doh! I should have seen that, thanks!

Comment: Nice! I added it as an answer so it is clear for the new visitors that the question was solved. You can accept it if you want!

Answer (score 0):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139873/use-hash-tag-and-in-launching-url-with-bash-shell-script/19139961#comment28307452_19139873), this should make it:

```
midori "http://www.test.com/test.php?id=$i&test=yes#test(test)" &
```

Note that giving the parameter within double quotes makes `midori` understand it as a string. As you were giving it without any quote, bash was trying to interpret it and getting puzzled with the `(` in `(test)`.